# Python, find a specific character in a string in a list

Tags: python

If the character at index 0 of the current item is the letter "a", continue to the next one. Otherwise, print out the current member.
Example: `["abc", "xyz"]` will just print "xyz".

```python
def loopy(items):
    for item in items:
        if item[0] == "a":
            continue
        else:
            print(items)
```

Comment: `print(items) -> print(item)`

Comment: you want all items not starting with **a** or all items after the first starting with **a**?

Comment: Agree with @MosesKoledoye but you should post what the specific error is (which you did not do) and what is expected (which you did).

Comment: and also you have an indentation problem

Comment: @bogdanciobanu He wants all items that DO NOT start with 'a'

Comment: I suggest using a list comprehension. `result = [i for i in items if not i.startswith('a')]`

Answer (score 1):

How about a `filter`?

```
In [191]: print('\n'.join(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'a', ["abc", "xyz", "test"])))
xyz
test
```

Comment: Does he want a list or he simply wants to print items (i.e., one per line)?

Comment: @AGNGazer The question is open to interpretation :) Probably the latter, but that's just an extension of this.

Answer (score 0):

with few correction :

```
>>> l=['abi', 'crei', 'fci', 'anfe']
>>> def loopy(list):
...     for i in list:
...             if i[0]=='a':
...                     continue
...             else:
...                     print i
... 
>>> loopy(l)
crei
fci
```

that you can make shorter this way :

```
>>> def loopy(list):
...     for i in list: 
...             if i[0]!='a':
...                     print i
... 
>>> loopy(l)
crei
fci
```

or to print in one line :

```
>>> def loopy3(list):
...     for i in list:
...             print i if i[0]!='a' else '',
... 
>>> loopy3(l)
 crei fci
```

but you can also use a list comprehension as suggest by bogdanciobanu :

```
>>> def loopy2(list):
...     print [i for i in list if i[0]!='a']
>>> loopy2(l)
['crei', 'fci']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def loopy(items):
    for item in items:
        if not item.startswith('a'):
            print(item)
```